# How to trace SQL queries sent by geo Server to Oracle database?

Tags: geoserver, wfs, oracle-dbms, debugging

When I open GML view of WFS layer in geoserver, it throws this exception:

"java.io.IOExceptionORA-00918: column ambiguously defined"
I am unable to trace SQL queries sent by geo Server to Oracle database.

Comment: Turn GeoServer logging into "geotools developer" mode.

Comment: Have you already made a search by the Oracle error ID?. Are you doing joins somewhere? See http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_00918_column_ambiguously_defined.htm

Comment: @user30184 major problem is that geo server doesn't show any query to debug it just take table name while adding a new layer.

Answer (score 5):

As already suggested by user30184:

- Go in the global settings and switch the logging level to GEOTOOLS_DEVELOPER_LOGGING, see http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/configuration/globalsettings.html#config-globalsettings
- Look in the logs for details about the queries being run, either directly on `$GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR/logs/geoserver.log` or from the web UI, "Geoserver logs" page

Comment: @user30184 thanks i got the issue. i found that the geo sever is repeating  the columns in query which creates the ambiguity.
here is the query auto generated from geo server
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT KHASRA,MAUZA_NAME,SECTION4,SECTION13,GEOMETRY as GEOMETRY
       ,KHASRA,MAUZA_NAME,SECTION4,SECTION13,GEOMETRY as GEOMETRY,
        KHASRA,MAUZA_NAME,SECTION4,SECTION13,GEOMETRY as GEOMETRY 
        FROM SHP_JT_MASSAVI)
WHERE ROWNUM <= 50

Comment: @user30184 please help me to resolve this issue please!

Comment: I do not understand how it happens. There must be something abnormal in the database or in the way you have created the store and layer.